Why did Slater bring Lucas to the island in "Blink Twice"?
In Blink Twice (2024), Slater (played by Channing Tatum) brings several women to his private island,

 where he, along with his friends Vic, Cody, and Tom, sexually assault them, using a perfume made from a flower called Desideria to make their victims forget the attacks, allowing the cycle to continue day after day.

The presence of Lucas (played by Levon Hawke) on the island seems puzzling given his non-participation in these activities.
Lucas doesn't seem to fit into Slater's plan. Unlike the other men, Lucas clearly doesn't want to participate, telling Slater "this is so fucked up" during one incident. Lucas himself has to be drugged with the flower's perfume (presumably by Slater). At one point, he even receives a black eye during the attacks, with Slater later claiming that Lucas "did nothing" during these assaults.
Interestingly, in one scene, Lucas is shown wearing clothing similar to what the women wear—something loose, long, and draped. This outfit could be easily removed and might hinder escape attempts.
This detail might suggest that Lucas is an intended victim for those who prefer men over women; however, this is just my speculation.

Given Lucas' obvious reluctance to participate and the potential risk he poses to their operation, what was Slater's motivation for bringing him to the island in the first place?
